# MIM to Expand AD Nested Groups and Create new AD group with all members

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, identity

I am interested in knowing how to use MIM & MIMWAL to create new AD groups from current Nested Group. I will require the new group to have members of all nested groups. Once the new group is provisioned in MIM metaverse i can sync this new group back to AD. What will the best approach for this. The client do not want to use any Powershell script. They want this solution to be implemented using MIM.

IS their guide for implementing this using MIMWAL. How do i approach this.

Regards

Vimal Vamadevan

Answer (score 0):

One way I have seen this been approached in the past for similar scenarios is by implementing a management agent whose purpose is to create new groups with the new memberships.  You would first bring in the existing (nested) groups from your AD forests to the MV, and then would export the (nested) groups and their memberships to this management agent, which would then cache them in some tabular or hierarchical structure on disk. Then, when requested to provide a full import, that management agent would then traverse the data structure to construct new groups.  I presume you have some filtering constraint on which groups to have this management agent construct - e.g., you don't need copies of every AD group.  Then you would flow from this management agent to the MV, and from the MV export back new groups to the source AD system.

The advantage of doing this in a management agent is that you can also perform other transformation or logic checks on the data structure as a whole, since following the export, your management agent would have all the relevant relationships and attributes from all the forests.  E.g., detect and warn on circular references, or transform one type of relationship to another such as for cross-forest groups.

I do not know of someone using MIMWAL to expand arbitrarily deeply nested groups, since that would require writing a complex iteration workflow to drive it.  But if you did want to go the MIMWAL route you might wish to also check at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=Mimwal

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay. So i already have a Management agent to import data to MV.  I have setup the flow inbound flow for group so the groups get created in MIM. Do i need to create a second AD MA. Are you refering to something slimier to this article. https://github.com/Microsoft/MIMWAL/wiki/Dynamic-Memberhsip-Notifications. In this articke they are expanding the group members. Can i do this config for the same using single AD MA or i need to create another one.

Comment: Also Using MIM MA how do i expand nested groups.